# Using linux sockets the QT way?

Tags: linux, qt, sockets, qt4

I have been googling this, but I can't seems to find it.

Is there a QT way to use linux sockets? It looked like the QSocket class is used for network sockets and not for local linux sockets.

Anyone knows anything about this? And maybe a tutorial to get started?

Comment: Have you checked `QLocalSocket`?

Comment: I've looked before and haven't found anything provided.  We ended up spawning threads to do reads in a 0-millisecond timeout slot.

Comment: If you want to take control over already created unix socket you can use QSocketNotifier. It reacts on reads/writes etc on your socket

Answer (score 5, accepted):

QSocket ? I think you're looking at the wrong Qt version :)

For the recommended Qt (4.6) there is QTcpSocket for TCP sockets. If you mean local domain sockets there is QLocalSocket.

http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.6/qtcpsocket.html

http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.6/qlocalsocket.html

Do not use a 0-timer and do not use threads.
There is no need for that, you get notified with the readyRead() signal if there is new data.

Answer (score 2):

Look at 'Local Fortune Client' and 'Local Fortune Server', under IPC in the QtCreator demos. Those use QLocalSocket, which is a local domain socket in *nix.